# glassfish server can't restart can't run

Tags: java, glassfish

Yesterday I switched off my computer and my project was working.
Today I can't run myproject and glassfish server particularly without visible reasons.
This is my console lo

```
    [2015-01-09T19:18:14.134+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-CORE-00090] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1420809494134] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Internal Server error: /__asadmin/set
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
]]
[2015-01-09T19:18:14.524+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-CORE-00091] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=42 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1420809494524] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Unable to set customized error page
java.io.IOException
]]
[2015-01-09T19:18:15.135+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=513 _ThreadName=pool-231-thread-1] [timeMillis: 1420809495135] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.15 started in: 518ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]
[2015-01-09T19:18:15.433+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=517 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1420809495433] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JdbcRuntimeExtension,  getAllSystemRAResourcesAndPools = [GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcConnectionPool, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource, GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.jdbc.config.JdbcResource]]]
[2015-01-09T19:18:16.217+0600] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [ra.stop-successful] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=525 _ThreadName=Thread-98] [timeMillis: 1420809496217] [levelValue: 800] [[
  RAR7094: __ds_jdbc_ra shutdown successful.]]
```

Comment: JSF and Java-EE are not part of the problem. I cannot specifically understand what's going on with your glassfish installation, so an alternative would be to reinstall glassfish and reconfigure it.

Comment: What do you mean by you can't restart the server? What is happening then?

Answer (score 0):

Having similar issue right now.

```
[2016-04-01T12:58:47.165+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-CORE-00090] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=48 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1459508327165] [levelValue: 900] [[
Internal Server error: /__asadmin/__locations
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Connection is closed
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:266)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
```

When I looked closer on my server.log I found that before this exception there was another one:

```
[2016-04-01T12:58:45.064+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00019] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1459508325064] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
```

So some other process may block glassfish from starting. I turned off apache-karaf console (which I was playing around recently) and started domain again with success. 
Are there any processes not connected with glassfish on yout machine that can block? Any OSGI tools?

Probably this is too late for this answer but I posted my observation for others to have any clue what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check the domains '**config.xml**' files status. As long as these lines collides on ports sharing, no listener will work. It could be any port on your side.

```
 <network-listeners>
      <network-listener protocol="http-listener-1" port="8080" name="http-listener-1" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp" />
      <network-listener protocol="http-listener-2" port="8181" name="http-listener-2" thread-pool="http-thread-pool" transport="tcp" />
      <network-listener protocol="admin-listener" port="4848" name="admin-listener" thread-pool="admin-thread-pool" transport="tcp" />
    </network-listeners>
```

- *C:.....\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml*
- *C:.....\domains\domain2\config\domain.xml*